# What meaning 'vanish' in math

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

I am an Italian engineering student and I am studying Differential Geometry from "Analysis on manifolds" by Jams R. Munkres and I'd like to discuss the meaning of the verb "to vanish" in the following theorem. Here the text.

[image]

Does **f vanishes except on a set of measure zero** mean that for any set that does not have not measure zero,

- there exists a point *x* such that *f(x) **=** 0*

or that

- there exists a point *x* such that *f(x) **→** 0*?

So could someone help me, please?

Comment: 'Vanish' in this usage _does_ mean 'have value zero'. But the question is really more about maths than general English usage.

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network: Mathematics.SE (Perhaps the 'terminology' tag.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Okay, so this means that there exist a point x such that f(x)=0?

Comment: Probably not the mapping arrow. That would be defined between _Q_ and _**ℝ**_ but not between _f_ and 0.

Comment: I think he means f goes to zero as a limit.

Comment: f is identically zero at all points in Q except for a set of zero measure. If you pick a subset of Q that has non-zero measure -- let's call it S -- f would vanish at points in S except perhaps for a subset of S that has zero measure. This does not belong on ELU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[Vanishing:](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Vanishing.html)***

> A quantity which takes on the value zero is said to vanish.
>
> For example, the function f(z)=z^2 vanishes at the point z=0. For
> emphasis, the term "vanish identically" is sometimes used instead,
> meaning the quantity in question does not merely vanish by all
> appearances, but is mathematically identically equal to zero.
>
> A quantity that is nonzero everywhere is said to be [nonvanishing.](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Nonvanishing.html)

(mathworld.wolfram.com)

Comment: Good answer (including reference).

Comment: My understanding of *vanishing* (as distinct from vanish or vanished) has always been that something is approaching but has not yet assumed the value of zero. In other words, vanishing means *extremely small* (and perhaps, likely to get smaller as time goes on).

Comment: @Steve In all the mathematical texts I've seen, "to vanish" always means "to equal zero". So "vanishing" means "equaling zero", not "approaching zero" or anything like that.

Comment: @Steve In that sense, of being small, I would use *vanishing* as an adjective: *it's vanishing small …* I've never heard *vanishing* used on its own in that sense before.

Comment: @JasonBassford, yes I mean exactly in usages such as "vanishingly small". I know the OP asked about "vanish", but Hachi here gives a definition for "vanishing".